# Grails: plugins-list.xml page not found

Tags: grails

https://grails.org/.plugin-meta/plugins-list.xml

We're sorry, but the page you requested appears not to exist.

Does anyone have any idea when this file will be back on the grails.org site since it is impacting our build process.

**Updated**

Thanks for the correct URL, the issue appears to be even within the XML file that the urls also have plugin.grails which actually does not appear to be working here is an example:

Problem appears

http://plugins.grails.org/grails-quartz/tags/RELEASE_0_4_2/grails-quartz-0.4.2.zip

Should be

http://grails.org/plugins/grails-quartz/tags/RELEASE_0_4_2/grails-quartz-0.4.2.zip

when you go to :
http://grails.org/plugins/.plugin-meta/plugins-list.xml
It states :

```
<plugin name="quartz" latest-release="1.0.1">..

<description>Adds Quartz job scheduling features</description>
<file>http://plugins.grails.org/grails-quartz/tags/RELEASE_0_4_1-SNAPSHOT/grails-quartz-0.4.1-SNAPSHOT.zip</file>
</release>
```

This link as above findings should be grails.org/plugins and not plugins.grails.org

**Issue at hand and quickest fix**

Sorry forgot to mention all of this earlier, it seems since the 9th some change was done at your end (unsure what it did before or if it fully resolved)

Now the subdomain redirects to grails.org/plugins:

plugins.grails.org -> http://grails.org/plugins/

When I was testing those url's the url ended up something like  http://grails.org/plugins/plugins/

The quickest fix which involves not having to change any XML file content or any other issue that may arise from it is to set up I guess

if its a folder a symlink might be easiest fix or:

```
cd plugins ln -s ../plugins ./
```

if not I guess a redirect :

```
Redirect /plugins/plugins  http://grails.org/plugins
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link is incorrect, it is http://grails.org/plugins/.plugin-meta/plugins-list.xml

Comment: Issue is within the generated XML File:  an example: http://plugins.grails.org/grails-quartz/tags/RELEASE_0_4_2/grails-quartz-0.4.2.zip

Should be

http://grails.org/plugins/grails-quartz/tags/RELEASE_0_4_2/grails-quartz-0.4.2.zip

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the grails_core project I can see this version is very different to current file, the following changes / hacks was put in to get around current issue:

_PluginDependencies.groovy

```
74,85d58
< 
< CORE_PLUGIN_DIST = "http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins"
< CORE_PUBLISH_URL = "https://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins"
< //DEFAULT_PLUGIN_DIST = "http://plugins.grails.org"
< DEFAULT_PLUGIN_DIST = "http://grails.org"

281,282d280
<   remoteURL="$targetRepoURL/plugins/"
< 

986,991d980
<   if (pluginDistName.indexOf('plugins.grails.org')>-1) {
<           //def start=pluginsBase.substring(0,pluginsBase.indexOf('plugins.grails.org'));
<                 //def end=pluginsBase.substring(start,pluginsBase.length());
<                 def end=pluginDistName.substring(26,pluginDistName.length())
<                   pluginDistName="${remoteURL}${end}"
<         }
1006a996
```

This has fixed our issue and the xml is now being pulled and its content working fine. Unsure if there was anything else missing.